# Is there a V2 Router for BaseSwap DEX on the Base Chain Testnet?

Tags: addresses, testnets, decentralized-exchange, coinbase, router

I am currently working with the **BaseSwap** decentralized exchange that runs on the **Base Chain**. I noticed that they have a router for facilitating transactions on **mainnet**, but I am particularly interested in knowing if there is a version 2 (V2) router address available on their **testnet**.

Does anyone have information regarding the availability of a **V2 Router** address for **BaseSwap DEX** on the Base Chain testnet?

Thank you for your assistance.